# control number two digit reverse

Tags: vb.net

The control number of the number 347842 is: `3+4+7+8+4+2= 28=2+8+10= 1`

I want a model for the development of an algorithm, to show the variants of this control number for 2 numbers: (from 1 to 80) - I will present an example below for the control Digit that will be 1: 2, 3 and 15. (so the control number will be from 1 to 15, for 2 numbers. and the algorithm will perform all the numbers generated from 1-80 that match.

1= 01, 10,

2 = 02, 11, 20,

3 = 03, 12, 21, 30,

15 = 06, 15, 69, 78 and so on...

and so on...

how could i make an algorithm based on this presented model?

Comment: Shouldn't `15`'s control number be `6`? I think there's something I don't get right.

Comment: exactly, I have changed now.

Comment: Generate and save the control numbers for 1-80. When asked for the numbers which have a particular control number, look them up.

Comment: yes, that would be an idea, and probably the simplest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in 2 steps:

1. Recursive function which gives you the control number.
2. Loop which finds all the numbers corresponding to each control number and store them accordingly.

## 1

```
Private Function GetControlNumber(num As Integer) As Integer
    If num > 9 Then
        Dim sum As Integer = 0
        For Each car As Char In num.ToString
            sum += Asc(car) - 48 'numbers starts at 48 in the ascii chart
        Next

        Return GetControlNumber(sum)
    End If

    Return num
End Function
```

## 2

```
Private Sub StoreNumbers()
    Dim controlNumbers As New Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of Integer))

    For i As Integer = 0 To 80
        Dim controlValue As Integer = GetControlNumber(i)

        If Not controlNumbers.ContainsKey(controlValue) Then
            'add the key if it hasn't been done yet
            controlNumbers.Add(controlValue, New List(Of Integer))
        End If

        'add the value to the right key
        controlNumbers(controlValue).Add(i)
    Next

    'proof of concept, you can get this off the algorithm once you verified your success
    For Each i As Integer In controlNumbers(1)
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

Have fun!

Comment: it works, it gave me a little headache to understand the process and the algorithm, finally I managed to get it to work.

Comment: Good job! I know the dictionary thing is a big step, but I love dictionaries, they are awesome! (and I also am a recursion enthusiast, so there's that)